# Android Camera2 API How to get initial focus point distance with inbuilt AUTOFOCUS routine of camera?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera2, autofocus

So basically I want to get the *focus distance* of lens when the focus mode is *AUTO*.

Currently I am working like this:

- Assuming `CONTROL_AF_MODE` is set to `CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO` by default.
- Trying to get `CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE` which returns `0.0` on  NEXUS 5 virtual device and `null` on Redmi Note 3.

Is it the correct logic?

Answer (score 1):

Generally the logic is correct. Just check a few details:

1. Make sure your device and specific camera support auto focus by checking [LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE).
2. Make sure `CONTROL_AF_STATE` is at least not `CONTROL_AF_STATE_INACTIVE`. Most likely you need to wait until it's actually focused.

Also note the type of this value is different on different devices. Check [LENS_INFO_FOCUS_DISTANCE_CALIBRATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#LENS_INFO_FOCUS_DISTANCE_CALIBRATION) to find out if it's a real distance or just some synthetic value.

Comment: I am getting `CONTROL_AF_MODE` value as 4. How do I know whether it is the value for `CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO` or not?

Comment: Check possible varies [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html#CONTROL_AF_MODE). 4 is `CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE`

Comment: Are the values listed in the documentation lies from 0 to 5 in sequential manner? And as per your answer, How does `LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE` can clarify whether device support auto focus or not? I mean it just gives the minimum focus distance value. I am new to android, so having these type of questions!